# jhipster vue npm audit fix --force error I don't know what to do, please help me

Tags: vue.js, npm, jhipster

I created the project with jhipster when I installed npm failed to perform a repair log as follows
I don't know what to do, please help me

```
 npm audit fix --force
```

log

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating generator-jhipster-vuejs to 0.0.3,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN deprecated formatio@1.1.1: This package is unmaintained. Use @sinonjs/formatio instead
npm WARN deprecated samsam@1.1.2: This package has been deprecated in favour of @sinonjs/samsam
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

added 374 packages, removed 88 packages, changed 14 packages, and audited 2751 packages in 44s

101 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

axios  <0.21.1
Severity: high
Server-Side Request Forgery - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1594
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/axios
  generator-jhipster  2.19.0 - 7.0.0-beta.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of axios
  Depends on vulnerable versions of jhipster-core
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
  node_modules/generator-jhipster

braces  <2.3.1
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/786
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/braces
  micromatch  0.2.0 - 2.3.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of braces
  node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/micromatch
    glob-stream  5.3.0 - 5.3.5
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    node_modules/glob-stream
      vinyl-fs  2.4.2 - 2.4.4
      Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-stream
      node_modules/vinyl-fs

decompress  <4.2.1
Severity: high
Arbitrary File Write - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1217
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install generator-jhipster-vuejs@1.9.2, which is a breaking change
node_modules/decompress
  gulp-decompress  <=1.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of decompress
  node_modules/gulp-decompress
    download  4.0.0 - 5.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of caw
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gulp-decompress
    node_modules/download
      yeoman-generator  <=0.24.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of download
      Depends on vulnerable versions of html-wiring
      Depends on vulnerable versions of inquirer
      Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
      node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs/node_modules/yeoman-generator
        generator-jhipster-vuejs  <=0.0.3
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yeoman-generator
        node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs

deep-extend  <=0.5.0
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/612
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs/node_modules/deep-extend
  mem-fs-editor  2.1.0 - 3.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of deep-extend
  node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs/node_modules/mem-fs-editor

lodash  <=4.17.18
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1065
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1523
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/577
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/782
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install generator-jhipster-vuejs@1.9.2, which is a breaking change
node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/lodash
node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs/node_modules/lodash
node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/lodash
node_modules/jhipster-core/node_modules/lodash
  cheerio  0.14.0 - 0.19.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
  node_modules/cheerio
    html-wiring  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cheerio
    node_modules/html-wiring
      yeoman-generator  <=0.24.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of download
      Depends on vulnerable versions of html-wiring
      Depends on vulnerable versions of inquirer
      Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
      node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs/node_modules/yeoman-generator
        generator-jhipster-vuejs  <=0.0.3
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yeoman-generator
        node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs
  generator-jhipster  2.19.0 - 7.0.0-beta.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of axios
  Depends on vulnerable versions of jhipster-core
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
  node_modules/generator-jhipster
  inquirer  <=0.11.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
  node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs/node_modules/inquirer
  jhipster-core  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
  node_modules/jhipster-core

tunnel-agent  <0.6.0
Severity: moderate
Memory Exposure - https://npmjs.com/advisories/598
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install generator-jhipster-vuejs@1.9.2, which is a breaking change
node_modules/caw/node_modules/tunnel-agent
  caw  <=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of tunnel-agent
  node_modules/caw
    download  4.0.0 - 5.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of caw
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gulp-decompress
    node_modules/download
      yeoman-generator  <=0.24.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of download
      Depends on vulnerable versions of html-wiring
      Depends on vulnerable versions of inquirer
      Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
      node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs/node_modules/yeoman-generator
        generator-jhipster-vuejs  <=0.0.3
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yeoman-generator
        node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs

20 vulnerabilities (7 low, 2 moderate, 11 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

Comment: I updated NodeJS to fix it